# Texture loading for custom Geometry using ShaderMaterial is not working in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

Here, i have a Geometry(pyramid) with four vertices and 4 faces -

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,100,0), new THREE.Vector3(-100,-100,100), new THREE.Vector3(0,-100,-100), new THREE.Vector3(100,-100,100));
geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 3), new THREE.Face3( 0, 3, 2), new THREE.Face3( 1, 2, 3) );
geom.computeFaceNormals();
```

Here is my RawShaderMaterial -

```
var geomMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: [
            'precision highp float;',
            'precision highp int;',
            'uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;',
            'uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;',
            'attribute vec3 position;',
            'attribute vec2 uv;',
            'varying vec2 interpolatedUV;',
            'void main() {',
            'interpolatedUV = uv;',
            'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        fragmentShader: [
            'precision highp float;',
            'precision highp int;',
            'uniform sampler2D texSampler;',
            'varying vec2 interpolatedUV;',
            'void main() {',
            'gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler, interpolatedUV);',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        uniforms: {
            texSampler: {
                type: 't',
                value: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/test.png")
            }
        }
    });
```

"images/test.png" is accessible from the script. It seems pretty much trivial to me but the texture simply does not show up. All i can see is a white pyramid.

Can you please tell me what actually went wrong with it?

**UPDATE:**

After digging around, i have found that i have to provide the UV map for the custom geometry i have created. So i have added it this way -

```
var uvs = [];
    uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 1.0));
    uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.0));
    uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0.0, 0.0));
    uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(1.0, 0.0));

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 1));
    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs[0], uvs[2], uvs[1]);

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 3));
    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs[0], uvs[1], uvs[3]);

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 3, 2));
    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs[0], uvs[3], uvs[2]);

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 1, 2, 3));
    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs[1], uvs[2], uvs[3]);
```

But it still shows the white pyramid.And also i am getting this error now -

> THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 0
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 1
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 2
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 3
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 4
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 5
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 6
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 7
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 8
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 9
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 10
>   THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector2sArray(): vector is undefined 11

Any idea about it?

Comment: No errors? I thought the raw shader material doesnt give you projectionMatrix MVMatrix etc.

Comment: If i remove my custom geometry and provide a sphereGeometry, it works fine. SO i think the problem is not there.

Comment: do gl_FragColor  = vec4(  abs( interpolatedUV ) , 0. , 1.); 

see if it gives any color

Comment: hmm, interpolatedUV contains (0, 0) for every fragment. That means the attribute "uv" is not getting passed to the vertex shader. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: last made geometry like that at some 60 something version :) 

Not entirely sure, but its a start.

Comment: are you sure youre supposed to push to faceVertexUvs[0]?

Comment: I think, yes. I have checked with 3 different tutorial. All are doing the same. They are pushing all of the UVs to faceVertexUvs[0].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After debugging the code of Three.js, i have found the problem. I am writing it down as an answer since others can face the same problem.

Three.js treat Geometry.faceVertexUvs as an array of a set of UVs where each set represents all UVs of a single face. Here is the code snippet where they take the UVs from Geometry.faceVertexUvs -

```
if(!0===e){
     w=d[0][k];// here d=Geometry.faceVertexUvs and k=the index of the face

     if(void 0!==w)
       this.uvs.push(w[0],w[1],w[2]);
     else{
       console.warn("THREE.DirectGeometry.fromGeometry(): Undefined vertexUv ", k);
       this.uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2,new THREE.Vector2,new THREE.Vector2);
     }
}
```

So, the solution is to provide Geometry.faceVertexUvs as an array of FaceUvs. Here is my rough solution -

```
var faceUvs = [[],[],[],[]];
faceUvs[0].push(uvs[0], uvs[2], uvs[1]);
faceUvs[1].push(uvs[0], uvs[1], uvs[3]);
faceUvs[2].push(uvs[0], uvs[3], uvs[2]);
faceUvs[3].push(uvs[1], uvs[2], uvs[3]);
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(faceUvs[0]);
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(faceUvs[1]);
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(faceUvs[2]);
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push(faceUvs[3]);
```